# Validating Form with Javascript before running Ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, validation

Let me try to explain myself clearly. I want to use javascript to validate my form and once everything is filled in, I would like to execute the Ajax that I have ready.

This is my javascript code that I want to use to validate my form:

```
function validateForm(frm) {
  var age = frm.age.value,
  height_ft = frm.height_ft.value,
  height_in = frm.height_in.value,
  weight = frm.weight.value;

  if (isNaN(age) || age == ""){
    alert("Please enter your age, numbers only.");
    frm.age.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if (isNaN(height_ft) || isNaN(height_in) || height_ft == "" || height_in == "") {
    alert("Please enter your height, numbers only.");
    return false;
  }

  if (isNaN(weight) || weight == "") {
    alert("Please enter your weight, numbers only.");
    frm.weight.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
```

Now below is my Ajax code:

```
$("#submit").click( function() {
  $.post( $("#weightFrm").attr("action"),
         $("#weightFrm :input").serializeArray(),
         function(info) { 
            $("#ack").empty();
            $("#ack").html(info);
         });
});

$("#weightFrm").submit( function() {
   return false;    
});
```

Now the Ajax code works flawlessly, but I would like to validate all the information first and then submit once everything is filled in. Any help would be taken.

```
 <form id="weightFrm" action="form_submit.php" onclick="return validateForm(this);" method="post">
```

Comment: Do the `ajax` when the form is valid in validateform().

Comment: @sgtBOSE I tried running if right after but it reloads the page and opens up form_submit.php

Answer (score 0):

do it like this

```
function validateForm(frm) {
    var age = frm.age.value,
        height_ft = frm.height_ft.value,
        height_in = frm.height_in.value,
        weight = frm.weight.value;

    if (isNaN(age) || age == ""){
        alert("Please enter your age, numbers only.");
        frm.age.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if (isNaN(height_ft) || isNaN(height_in) || height_ft == "" || height_in == "") {
        alert("Please enter your height, numbers only.");
        return false;
    }
    else if (isNaN(weight) || weight == "") {
        alert("Please enter your weight, numbers only.");
        frm.weight.focus();
        return false;
    }else {
    $.post( $("#weightFrm").attr("action"),
             $("#weightFrm :input").serializeArray(),
             function(info) { 
                $("#ack").empty();
                $("#ack").html(info);
             });

    $("#weightFrm").submit( function() {
       return false;    
    });

    }}
```

Comment: I tried your code I was doing something similar and it opens the the action .php file

Answer (score 0):

Hook into the form submission instead of the submit click, this way you'll be able to stop the form from submitting.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Validate here.

    // AJAX here.
});
```

Comment: Where would this go exactly? sorry

Comment: This would go in a `<script>` tag anywhere after jQuery has added to your HTML page, you'd have to ensure it is not initialized until after DOM.ready. In jQuery that would mean wrapping it in `$(document).ready(function( ... ){});`

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the form in real time using jQuery as shown below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>xyz</title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="number" id="age">
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#age").on("input",function(){
        if(!$.isNumeric($("#age").val()))
        {
             alert("Age must be numeric!");
        }
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey sorry im kinda new to jQuery, where would I put this in my code?

Comment: First load jquery `<script src="jquery.js"></script>` Then you can add the above code anywhere in your document after loading jquery. I have edited the code for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `onclick` method in form but use `onsubmit`. The desired behaviour that you are expecting should be changed to following

```
$("#submit").click( function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(!validateForm(this))
     return false;
  $.post( $("#weightFrm").attr("action"),
     $("#weightFrm :input").serializeArray(),
     function(info) { 
        $("#ack").empty();
        $("#ack").html(info);
      }
  );
  return false;
});
```

Comment: I tried this but it opens the form in a new page instead of not reloading.

Comment: I edited my answer, check the click event is applied to submit button not form.

Comment: Alright so I tried it and nothing is happening, for the <form> do I use onclick or onsubmit? doesn't the code u gave me run it from there? I also tried putting onclick on the submit button but nothing. Thanks